# Rendering a closed Marionette view

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

Shouldn't a closed Marionette view re-delegate the defined events (events, modelEvents, CollectionEvents) when rendering again?

It seems as if I have to manually call delegateEvents after closing and re-rendering a view. Otherwise the view won't work as expected.

http://jsfiddle.net/4DCeY/

```
var app = new Marionette.Application();

app.addRegions({
    main: '.main'
});

var MyView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({

    template: _.template('Hi, I\'m a view! Foo is: <%= foo %>'),

    modelEvents: {
        'change': 'onChange'
    },

    onChange: function() {
        alert('change!');
    }
});


var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({});


app.addInitializer(function() {
    var m = new Model({foo: 'bar'});
    var myView = new MyView({
        model: m
    });

    app.main.show(myView);
    myView.close();
    app.main.show(myView);

    m.set({foo: 'baz'});

});

$(document).ready(function(){
    app.start();
});
```

Comment: it should and it does, you are probably doing something wrong in the view, can you paste the code of your problematic view

Comment: Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4DCeY/ If everything would work fine, the alert message should be displayed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your question right, there are multiple open github issues about this.

For example:

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/pull/654
https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/issues/622

Last time I checked, Derick (the creator of Marionette) didn't feel like reusing closed views should be something regions should do.

So you could

1. simply create a new view and show that one
2. manually call delegateEvents - but there was an issue with multiple event bindings that I can't remember right now, so be careful about that one (not at work right now, so can't take a peek at the code, sorry)
3. write your own region manager
4. or wait and see if Derick will merge one of the pull requests

Comment: Okay, thank you! I think I will try an own implementation. Just wanted to ensure there aren't any other ways to do this with marionette!

Comment: BTW: here is the original discussion on github: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/issues/223

Answer (score 0):

a couple of points:

1. You do not need to call myView.close() Marionette Region will take care of that when you show **another** view
2. Marionette.Region will not replace the same view with itself. It will just skip the redundant procedure if you want to test this correctly you need 2 views
3. If you want a change in model to invoke render you must explicitly write it

I altered the jsfiddle with the following things:

1. added myView1 and myView2
2. removed explicit call to myView.close
3. added a call for this.render() from the onChange function

Here is the corrected jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4DCeY/1/ :

```
app.addInitializer(function() {
   var m = new Model({foo: 'bar'});
   var myView1 = new MyView({
      model: m
   });
   var myView2 = new MyView({
      model: m
   });

   app.main.show(myView1);
   app.main.show(myView2);

   m.set({foo: 'baz'});

});
```

And:

```
onChange: function() {
    alert('change!');
    this.render();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I get your point, but we are talking about to different scenarios, I think. In my example I want to reuse the closed view, i don't want to replace it with another instance. No matter how the layout behaves, the view instance will be closed and rendered again.

Comment: @MalteWe - I am not sure I understand, Why do you close the view?