# DelegateEvents: Child itemViews's not removed on deletion of model from collection

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views, backbone-events

I've a `collectionview` `ItineraryEditorView` that is swapped in and out of a layout region.
The same instance of `collectionView` is swapped in using `region.show` instead of creating new instance for `collectioView` every time. The render method on the collection calls `delegateEvents()` method.

```
    ItineraryEditorView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    tagName: "div",
    emptyView: EmptyItineraryDayView,
    itemView: ItineraryDayView,
    initialize: function (options) {            
    },  
    render: function() {
        Marionette.CollectionView.prototype.render.apply(this);
        this.delegateEvents();
    },
});
```

The view is swapped out by closing region:

```
plannerLayout.itineraryEditorRegion.close();
```

Swapping in the view:

```
itineraryEditorView.delegateEvents();
plannerLayout.itineraryEditorRegion.show(itineraryEditorView);
```

Deletion of a model is done by listening to the bubbled up event from `itemView` to `collectionView` (works, no issues here)

```
itineraryEditorView.on("itemview:delete:day", function(childView, model)    {
    days.remove(model); //days coll is passed in to coll view on instance creation
    holiday.save();
});
```

I'd expect that this would be enough to ensure the the child `itemViews` in the collection view are removed/closed when a model is removed from the underlying days collection. I can see that the collection is actually modified and and saved on the server,however the collection view is not altered.
This scenario of course works when before the collection view is swapped out first time.
The coll. view does update itself after I re-visit another tab and come back to this tab (thus the entire collection is rendered- confirming the change/deletion)

What is the best way get around this issue? If I recreate the instance of collection view, it does cause to lose other "on" handles in the code.

Comment: The fact that you're calling delegateEvents manually makes me suspicious. Are you reusing your view after closing the region?

Comment: @chris yes I'm reusing views.

Comment: Marionette wasn't designed to reuse closed views. This thread might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17920499/rendering-a-closed-marionette-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to call `delegateEvents` manually - Backbone does this in the view's constructor. When you close the region, the region will close your view removing all internal references and unbinding all events, preparing it for garbage collection. Once a view has been `close()`'d, it should not be used again. The fix to your problem should be to `new` up another instance of your `ItineraryEditorView` and pass that to the region on `show`.

Also, it's not necessary to call `region.close()` before calling `region.show(view)`; the first thing `show` does is to `close()` the current view, if any. My recommendation to modify your code as follows:

```
ItineraryEditorView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    // tagName: "div", // <-- unnecessary as written - default tag

    emptyView: EmptyItineraryDayView,

    itemView: ItineraryDayView

    // this empty override is unnecessary as written - recommend removing it
    // initialize: function (options) {           
    // },

    // this override is unnecessary as written - remove it:
    // render: function() {
    //     Marionette.CollectionView.prototype.render.apply(this);
    //     this.delegateEvents();
    // },
});
```

...

```
// plannerLayout.itineraryEditorRegion.close(); <-- delete this line; it's not needed
// itineraryEditorView.delegateEvents();        <-- ditto
```

*EDITED FROM ORIGINAL POST*

```
// define a delegate to handle events shared across multiple instances of the view:
function handleDeleteChild(childView, model) {
    days.remove(model); //days coll is passed in to coll view on instance creation
    holiday.save();
});

// create the ItineraryEditorView
// NOTE: As written this will likely conflict with your current code;
//       update as required
var itineraryEditorView = new ItineraryEditorView(options);

// bind event listeners to it
itineraryEditorView.on("itemview:delete:day", handleDeleteChild);

// show it
plannerLayout.itineraryEditorRegion.show(itineraryEditorView);
```

Comment: thanks for reply. However if I use new instances of view, other application events viz. view.on("myevent") stop working. I've not being able to understand the reason for same but that's a separate question I guess? The only way then to get around is to not use this.trigger from within view, but pass in a layout instance to view and use layout.trigger instead!?

Comment: I've tried the above code by removing delegate event and the events don't work as expected. They do work after I call delegateEvents explicitly.

Comment: If you designed your app thinking you can reuse closed views then these symptoms make sense. The close operation should be considered a destructor (think C# or Java) for Marionette views. Once a view is closed, any external references you made to it need to be removed and any event listeners need to be unbound. Since you're creating a new view in its stead, you'll need to rebind all event listeners formerly attached to the old one.

Comment: I've modified the code to show how to rebind the `delete` event defined in your question; similar changes may need to be made elsewhere in your app.

Comment: The code you modified is a good option to follow (in shorter term). Thanks for sharing this. However, it does mean that to future proof the app, it might be better to take time now to rewrite some code and just use new views regardless if next versions of marrionette allows or disallow reusing of views.

Comment: Glad I could help! :) If it were me I'd invest the time to re-engineer the app under the assumption that Marionette will *never* support reusing closed views. This article is a little outdated, but it provides some history into how the `close` operation came into being and the problems it solves: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/